# Django, check if an object present in query set using exists() method

Tags: django

I have a below model,

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    head = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

I have created an object in Entry model, when I try to check if there is any objects in Entry model it shows error as attached image

[image]

Comment: `exists` is a queryset method, and `get` returns an object. Use `filter`instead.

Comment: It is `Entry.objects.filter(pk=1).exists()`, since `.get()` is not a `QuerySet`, but an `Entry` object in this case.

Comment: Thank you all,I have figured it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `Entry.objects.filter(pk=1).exists()`, since `.get()` is not a `QuerySet`, but an `Entry` object in this case. So you check with:

```
if Entry.objects.filter(pk=1).exists():
    # …
else:
    # …
```

Here however, it is probably simpler to work with a `try`-`except` clause, and thus work in an [*EAFP* style [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions):

```
try:
    entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)
    print('k')
except Entry.DoesNotExists:
    print('false')
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.William Van Onsem, your answers support and inspires

Answer (score 2):

If you need the object you can do:

```
entry = Entry.objects.filter(pk=1).first()
if entry:
    # …
else:
    # …
```

The `.first()` method returns `None` if the queryset is empty.